# C# Thread won't die properly unless I step through the code

Tags: c#, multithreading

My thread (_updater) is started by this:

```
 public void StartCollection()
    {
        running = true;
        _updater = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ContinuousCollect));
        _updater.Start();
    }
```

It then grabs data from the sensors and sends it out to where it's needed.

```
private void ContinuousCollect()
    {
        while (running) //Static Boolean that controls whether or not to keep running.
        {
            lock (_data)
                ReadData(ref _data);

            //Stuff that doesn't matter
        }
    }
```

Then it is stopped by this method:

```
 public void StopCollection()
    {
        if (_updater != null)
        {
            if (_updater.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)
            {
                running = false;
                _updater.Join();
            }

            _updater = null;
        }
    }
```

When I run it normally with no breakpoints, it will throw an error when it tries to read data but I've closed the COM port already - which it shouldn't be doing as I've tried to end the thread. When I use a breakpoint though in the StopCollection() and step through, it properly changes running to false and _updater grinds to a stop, resulting in no errors. Without the breakpoints, _updater continues running even after I call StopCollection(), and running remains set to true, even though the only location in the code where I set it to true is in StartCollection(). I tried using Thread.Abort but that didn't work either. What can I do?

Comment: Have you considered using `Task.Factory.StartNew` with `CancellationToken` ?

Comment: Where do you close the port?

Comment: In the method a method that calls StopCollection(); after it calls StopCollection() it closes the port.

Comment: ...and you're **definitely** taking the `.Join` path when things don't work as expected?

Comment: Unless if (_updater.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running) isn't functioning, yes, I am. I ran it with the _updater != null commented out and the program still bugged out.

Comment: Hmm if the thread Joins then it must be stopped. Can you add some debug messages to see if you are actually going through the if statement.

Comment: Your code is violating the .NET memory model, you will pay the price when you use the x86 jitter.  Declaring the bool variable *volatile* is a band-aid.  Using, say, an AutoResetEvent and testing it with WaitOne(0) is the correct fix.

Answer (score 2):

You're not synchronizing access to memory shared between your threads, which is the root of your problem.  Each thread is capable of caching the value of a particular state of memory so long as you don't explicitly prohibit it from doing so through the use of a memory barrier, so your worker thread is never checking the actual location in memory to see that you've updated the variable.

While it's possible for you to explicitly synchronize access to the variable in some way to ensure that it is properly accessed from multiple threads, the more idiomatic solution would be to use a `CancellationToken` instead, as it's implementation will ensure proper synchronization of the shared state, preventing the state of whether or not the token has been cancelled from being cached in other threads.

When debugging all sorts of optimizations are removed, as well as other behaviors modified in ways that change the results of undefined behaviors such as this one, which is why your program was behaving different when you were using the debugger.  Threading related bugs are very often difficult/impossible to reproduce using a debugger by their very nature, as the act of you observing the behavior changes the behavior itself, which is why you need to be so much more careful when programming in a multithreaded environment that uses shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Try making "running" a volatile field. Also do consider using Tasks and CancellationTokens as @Darek suggested

Answer (score 0):

I "fixed" the problem but probably caused another in the process. When it checked the state of the thread, a majority of the time the thread would be in `WaitSleepJoin`, causing the `if (_updater.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running)` to respond false and thus never disable the thread. Now it checks if it's `Running` or in `WaitSleepJoin` and if it's either, it changes the state of `Running` and the whole thing properly closes. Thanks everyone for helping!